# structure offset with bit field

Tags: c, data-structures, bit-fields

I have a question on getting the index offset to a field in the structure, below is the code I use to test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct ipv4_pkt_struct 
{
    /*ethernet hdr*/
    unsigned char   DestMacAddr[6]      ;
    unsigned char   SrcMacAddr[6]       ;
    unsigned char   EthernetType[2]     ;
    /*IP hdr*/
    unsigned char   Version           :4;
    unsigned char   IHL               :4;
    unsigned char   TypeofService[2]    ;
    unsigned char   Total_Length[4]    ;

} ipv4_pkt_struct_t; 

int main()
{

    ipv4_pkt_struct_t A;

    printf ("%d\n",(unsigned char*)A.TypeofService - (unsigned char*)A.DestMacAddr) ;
    printf("Hello World");

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
15                                                                                                        
Hello World
```

which is correct, but however if I do something like:

```
printf ("%d\n",(unsigned char*)A.IHL - (unsigned char*)A.DestMacAddr) ;
```

It will give me a very wired output:

```
1296908304                                                                                              
Hello World
```

and

```
printf ("%d\n",(unsigned char*)&A.IHL - (unsigned char*)A.DestMacAddr) ;
```

give an compile error:

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:29:5: error: cannot take address of bit-field 'IHL'
     printf ("%d\n",(unsigned char*)&A.IHL - (unsigned char*)A.DestMacAddr) ;
```

how can I get the correct offset ?

Comment: `(unsigned char*)A.IHL` -- You are casting a character to a pointer. What do you expect?

Comment: You have to use the address of your variable in all cases. Instead of (unsigned char*)A.IHL use (unsigned char*)&A.IHL.
And consider to use offsetof(...) to get the offset of a field in a struct.

Comment: What value of offset do you expect ? `14.5` bytes ? Offset can be integral value only. It doesn't make sense. You cannot get address of bit-field, so you cannot calculate offset to bit-field member.

Comment: Just don't use bit-fields, ever.

Comment: Just a sidenote: if you transport the struct via network (or let's say outside of your process) you might want to add __attribute__((packed )) as well.

Answer (score 3):

In C bit field members are not addressable.

n1570-§6.5.3.2 (p1):

> The operand of the unary `&` operator shall be either a function designator, the result of a `[]` or unary `*`operator, or an lvalue that designates **an object that is not a bit-field** [...]

Apart from that the line

```
printf ("%d\n",(unsigned char*)A.TypeofService - (unsigned char*)A.DestMacAddr) ;
```

should be

```
printf ("%td\n", A.TypeofService - A.DestMacAddr) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are casting an (uninitialized) unsigned char to a pointer; besides that accessing uninitialized data is undefined behaviour, even if you initialize it, you calculate with values and not with the addresses where these values reside.

I'd suggest to use [offsetof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof), which is build for exactly your usecase.

Comment: IIRC, `offsetof` cannot be used with bit fields. (neither can the address of operator as OP has used in the updated question).